# static or dynamic linking libcurl for C++ linux

Tags: c++, linux, g++, libcurl

I have C++ application for linux using `libcurl`.
The machine has `libcurl4-openssl-dev` installed, it compiles and works all right.

The compilation is done by

```
command: g++ test.cpp -lcurl -o test
```

Checking interaction:

```
ldd test
libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4 (0x0000003ff3400000)
```

Is it possible to extract `libcurl.so.4` from system directory `/usr/lib` and use it separately with my C++ application?

If so, how can I link it at the stage of compiling? 
If anybody has a real example of static or dynamic linking `libcurl` for C++ application?

Thanks!

Comment: Avoid static linking when possible. Use package management (e.g. by packaging your software as a `.deb` package) for dependencies.

Comment: Why do you want static linking? Dynamic libraries are here to get easily shared and updated....

Comment: Use The Source, Luke.

Comment: Basile Starynkevitch, how can i make dynamyc linked, but whith local files?